# returning null in linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

**I fill the data from xml in the model**

**Some xml tables don't have this(RequestedDeliveryDate,EarliestDeliveryDate,LatestDeliveryDate  ) property**

***For this reason return "Object reference not set to an instance of an object***

*Help me !!*

```
SchedulingConditions = _detailInformation.Descendants("SchedulingConditions").Select(_schedulingConditions => new SchedulingConditionsModel
{
    SchedulingConditionList = _schedulingConditions.Descendants("SchedulingCondition").Select(_schedulingCondition => new SchedulingCondition
    {
        QuantityToBeDelivered = _schedulingCondition.Element("QuantityToBeDelivered").Value,
        DeliveryPlan = _schedulingCondition.Element("DeliveryPlan").Value,
        Frequency = _schedulingCondition.Element("Frequency").Value,
        RequestedDeliveryDate = _schedulingCondition.Element("RequestedDeliveryDate").Value, --> This property is return null
        EarliestDeliveryDate =  _schedulingCondition.Element("EarliestDeliveryDate").Value, --> This property is return null
        LatestDeliveryDate = _schedulingCondition.Element("LatestDeliveryDate").Value  --> This property is return null 
    }).ToList(),
}).FirstOrDefault(),
```

Comment: Please add the definition of `SchedulingCondition` as the properties in this class will probably also need to be updated to support nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the property is null before trying to get value with "?". If the property is null, the return is null, if it is not null, the return is the property value.

```
SchedulingConditions = _detailInformation.Descendants("SchedulingConditions").Select(_schedulingConditions => new SchedulingConditionsModel
{

    SchedulingConditionList = _schedulingConditions.Descendants("SchedulingCondition").Select(_schedulingCondition => new SchedulingCondition
    {

        QuantityToBeDelivered = _schedulingCondition.Element("QuantityToBeDelivered").Value,
        DeliveryPlan = _schedulingCondition.Element("DeliveryPlan").Value,
        Frequency = _schedulingCondition.Element("Frequency").Value,
        RequestedDeliveryDate = _schedulingCondition.Element("RequestedDeliveryDate")?.Value, --> This property is return null
        EarliestDeliveryDate =  _schedulingCondition.Element("EarliestDeliveryDate")?.Value, --> This property is return null
        LatestDeliveryDate = _schedulingCondition.Element("LatestDeliveryDate")?.Value  --> This property is return null 

    }).ToList(),

}).FirstOrDefault(),
```

Comment: Hi @Hudson.The EarliestDeliveryDate property is sometimes missing in the XML tables I receive. So it will be null. This directly returns object reference not set to an instance error

Comment: Hello @MetehanSimsek. In this case, you could change the property too. For example: "DateTime?" with "?" you can set null in the property and DateTime became nullable. If your property type is already nullable, I think only add "?" to access the element is enoght.

Comment: Hi @Hudson Oliveira.My company is using a version lower than c#8.the feature you mentioned is for c# 8 and above.I need different way :(

Comment: Hi @MetehanSimsek. Got It, In this case, is a good idea to use a ValueObject pattern? I just to test C# 3 and 5 and it works for me. So I think the problem is your compile your something else codeproject.com/Articles/275471/Nullable-Types-in-Csharp-Net I sent an article with C# 4 and 2014 with Nullable<T>, I hope it could help you

Comment: Hi @Hudson.I solved problem.I used 'lastnode' event.Thank you very much for your efforts